# Solving and Plot Equation in Python

Tags: equations

I am kind of new to python. All I am trying to do is to solve for y and plot the function,
In other words, plug values for x and generate y.

```
y^10+y = x.
```

Please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

y = arange(-10, 10, 0.01) #get values between -10 and 10 with 0.01 step and set to y
x = y**10 + y #get x values from y

plot(x, y)
show()
```

[image: Plot result]

Using the matplotlib and numpy library: http://scipy.org/

If you want to solve things, use sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples